# If primes split nicely, is it a Galois extension?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of number fields.  When $L/K$ is Galois, the Galois group $\Gamma = \textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ acts transitively on the primes $\mathfrak P$ of $L$ lying over any given prime $\mathfrak p$.

For $\mathfrak P \mid \mathfrak p$, the ramification index $e(\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p)$ and residue degree $f(\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p)$ depend only on the extension of local rings $(\mathcal O_K)_{\mathfrak p} \subseteq (\mathcal O_L)_{\mathfrak P}$.  As any $\sigma \in \Gamma$ induces an isomorphism of localized rings $(\mathcal O_L)_{\mathfrak P} \rightarrow (\mathcal O_L)_{\sigma \mathfrak P}$, we can conclude that the numbers $e(\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p)$ and $f(\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p)$ are constant for all $\mathfrak P \mid \mathfrak p$.

Is the converse true?  That is, if for each $\mathfrak p$, the numbers $e(\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p)$ and $f(\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p)$ are constant for all $\mathfrak P \mid \mathfrak p$, can we conclude that $L/K$ is Galois?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I learned in [a question of mine on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34180/1916), the answer is yes, $L/K$ must be Galois.

It's basically due to [Chebotarev's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem).